# How can I copy a "*.img" image to a hard disc partition so that it will be bootable?

Tags: partitioning, backup, disk-image

There is an option for doing it from a Mac using Disk Utility; but at the moment I don't have a Mac.  So how do I do it using Windows or linux?

And how do I copy a `*.iso` image to a hard disc partition?

Comment: Do you want it to "AutoPlay/AutoRun" or do you just want to be able to access the files?

Answer (score 1):

[Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) doesn't quite burn it to your hard drive, it emulates a CD/DVD ROM in your system, allowing you to mount your "*.iso" to that virtual CD/DVD ROM. Alternatively if you want to just access the files, you can use [WinRaR](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html)

[Daemon Tools Download Link](http://eu-uk1.disc-tools.com/request?p=c27c62424a1babac4c3f172e790b9318/DTLite4451-0236.exe)